# Automatically mount all USB drives under certain folder

Tags: mount, raspbian, automounting

I'm trying to make Raspbian automatically mount all available paritions on USB devices under a certain folder.

I heard of fstab rules but those seem to require knowing the UUID of all devices meaning I'd have to pre-define what USB devices I can use which is not ideal.

I want the OS to automatically mount any plugged in USB device (both present at boot or not) under the folder `/storage` each partition on its own mount point (the names of the mounts can be anything, but should ideally not change between boots. This isn't a requirement however)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approaches to this would be (presuming you're not using a desktop environment where it's built-in) one of:

1. [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/wiki/Usage) with [udisks2](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/). This is more common, especially the udisks2 part which is what handles it under the "normal" desktop environments).
2. [udevil](https://ignorantguru.github.io/udevil/). This is intended as a lighter-weight alternative.
3. More specialized: code in your application interfacing with udisks2.

Note that the normal place these will be mounted is `/media`, not `/storage`. I'm not sure there is an easy way to override this; `/media` is the standard directory.

You'll also need to consider how the disks will be unmounted (before removing them); in the case of #3, your application would generally provide the option, or do it automatically when no longer in use. #1 or #2, you need to find some other way.

Comment: I had a look at `udiskie` but it only allows mounting to `/media/$USER/$DEV` or `/media/$DEV` which I eventually solved using symlinks. However, other users don't have write access to these devices which is a problem. Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: @user9123 Unfortunately you can't change the options udisks2 mounts with, it's hard-coded. There have been patches to change that (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33461 and https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/devkit-devel/2015-April/001668.html) but AFAICT they went nowhere. You'd want to change the `umask` flag if it were possible :-( You should be able to get it mounted as your user, though, if you only need one user to be able to write.

Comment: I tried `udevil` instead and it works great. The included daemon (`devmon`) can be easily run on startup (I used systemd for that) and you can set the permissions, mount locations, accepted filesystems etc. in the config (`/etc/udevil/udevil.conf` on Debian distros). Thanks! Marked as accepted.

Comment: @user9123 glad udevil worked out