# How can I automatically mount multiple disks on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without editing fstab?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, mount, disk

I have hundreds of disks that need to be plugged in on several Ubuntu desktops. Currently, the disks will not automatically mount under `/media/user/` (but can be found under `/dev/sd*`). However, with GUI, I can use the file explorer `Other locations` to show all the plugged-in disks. If I click one, it will be mounted and can be found at `/media/user/Disk-UUID`. The problem is, there are many disks that need to be clicked, and everything restores to original after reboot.

So, how can I write a script to mimic the behavior of clicking on the disks to automatically mount all disks that have been plugged in?

When I look up the method online, it seems that most people are talking about editing `/etc/fstab`. However, I do not want to do it this way, because I treat these disks as temporarily plugged in, do not want to name them, and do not want to make permanent changes to the system. Besides, after the disks being mounted, I see no entry in file `/etc/fstab`, so Ubuntu itself are doing it by other means. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551640/315749. Though no answer I could find included instructions on how to setup [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie) or any equivalent tool.

Comment: @fra-san I have tried this and failed:`$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdn --no-user-interaction
Error mounting /dev/sdn: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorizedCanObtain: Not authorized to perform operation`. If I remove `--no-user-interaction`, the problem is that it keeps asking me for password. How can I do it without inputting password?

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask a new question and link to this one to provide context, or, alternatively, edit this question and add what you have tried. Some more information is needed here - e.g. are you running  that command in a terminal emulator window? Which user is running it? Does that user also have an active GUI session? (This is required for that command to work). Comments aren't a good fit for this.

Comment: Thank you for your last edit! Since you have found a solution that works for you, I'd suggest you posting it as an answer to your own question so that it could be voted on and possibly improved; you may later accept it, signaling that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of @fra-san, I found that for a disk such as `/dev/sdn`, `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdn` is a simple way to achieve the goal. However, by default, that will require authentication. To avoid this, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, one needs to edit file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy`, and change the entries under `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system` (notice that there is another similar entry) to `yes`:

```
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

Then `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdn` will no longer require authentication and immediately mount the disk to `/media/user/Disk-UUID`.

Answer (score 0):

*Hundreds* of disks?

However:

> but can be found under /dev/sd*

Very well. So you can check those

```
for disk in /dev/sd*
```

and check whether they are mounted or not

```
    if (mount | grep "$disk" ); then
         echo already mounted
    else
```

retrieve their UUID

```
         UUID=$( blkid "$disk" )
```

possibly verify they are the correct filesystem, and then mount them on `/mnt/user/$UUID` or wherever you wish

```
         mount -t ext4 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it seems that udisksctl is a more simple solution.